# JavaFX: Save view of pane to image

Tags: java, javafx

Suppose I have N layers on a `StackPane`, I do blendings, drawings, images, rectangles etc on the `StackPane`. How would I go about saving the result? Ie what shows on my screen on the `StackPane`.

In general, suppose I have any drawable JavaFX element, how would I go about drawing that specific element to an imagefile.

I know swing would offer its `getGraphics()` for drawing directly to the pixel buffer of an image but I cannot find anything similar for `Node` or `Pane`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take a [`snapshot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) of the `Node` and save that to file

Covered in the following: [Take a snapshot with JavaFX!](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/take_a_snaphot_with_javafx)

---

I tend to use something like the below:

```
public void captureAndSaveDisplay(){
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    //Set extension filter
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png"));

    //Prompt user to select a file
    File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

    if(file != null){
        try {
            //Pad the capture area
            WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int)getWidth() + 20,
                    (int)getHeight() + 20);
            snapshot(null, writableImage);
            RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
            //Write the snapshot to the chosen file
            ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
        } catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty! I see now that my question is indeed a duplicate, google didnt turn up anything useful. I didnt even consider the word "snapshot" in my searches.